# Unity Switch between input fields with one click

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, input-field

I'm looking for a way to switch between input fields without having to double click the next input field twice.
What happens now is, for instance I type in something inside the first field, and then when I try to go to another field, I need to click on the other field once(or somewhere else besides the first input field) to remove focus, and then to click again on the other field to open up the keyboard and switch the focus to that field.

What can I do to make the switch between two input fields happen in one click(when clicking on the desired input field)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

From your problem, it seems like you are working on Android/iOS devices.
You could try calling [`TouchScreenKeyboard.Open()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.Open.html) when the InputField is clicked, like so:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(InputField))]
public class ShowKeyboardOnClick : MonoBehaviour {
    private InputField inputField;

    private void Awake() {
        inputField = GetComponent<InputField>();
    }

    // Or raycast, etc
    private void OnMouseDown() {
        TouchScreenKeyboard.Open(inputField.text);
    }
}
```

*Note that from the documentation, it states:*

> Only native iPhone, Android, and Windows Store Apps are supported.

Comment: Hi thanks, but unfortunately it does not work because keyboard opens up automatically